# TCL/expect for generating log file in xml or json format

Tags: json, xml, tcl, expect

Is there any way to generate the log file in xml or json format using TCL.
Using the log_file the logs are stored in text format.
Please suggest

Comment: People log in JSON? Really? (I know that Java can log in XML, and I also know that it's a bad idea…)

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use one of the JSON or XML libraries available for Tcl to write log messages in any format you want. Probably to put the data into one of those ELK stacks?

The expect `log_file` command takes the `-open` or `-leaveopen` argument with a tcl file identifier. Combine this with Tcl reflected channels and you can divert the log to some other logging system that writes the JSON you want.

See the documentation for [chan create](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/chan.htm#M22) and the API description at [refchan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/refchan.htm). For writing JSON, you can use [`json::write`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json_write.html) from tcllib.
You could probably adapt the code of [`tcl::chan::textwidget`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/virtchannel_base/textwindow.html) to dump out JSON instead of writing to a `text` widget.

Comment: My requirement is, i am running regression using TCL and the logs are captured in text format using log_file. Planning to use Jenkins for regression and for displaying the result we dont have any plugin that support text file. Please suggest if we have any better idea.

Comment: Well, whatever works. You could also write a Jenkins plugin. But i really doubt there is no text logfile plugin for jenkins, as it still is the most common case.